# Finding all files with extension .c, .h, and .java within my current directory

Tags: linux, command-line

I am trying to find all the files (ending with .c,.h and .java) that are in a folder or its subdirectories beginning with "new-". 
This is my current command: ls -R | egrep '.*[.]c$|.*[.]h$|.*[.]java$' 
What should I change?

Comment: You should change the question title to something more specific to your problem. :) [Do not parse `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs), use `find`.

Comment: Does `"new-"` refer to to files to be found? or subdirectories to be searched?

Comment: It's the first time I'm using this site :) 
It is requested that I use ls. It applies to subdirectories.

Comment: Please provide some example file paths that you want to locate.

Comment: Which of these directories would be valid places for the files you want to find? `./`, `./new-a/`, `./new-a/foo/`, `./bar/new-b/`, `./bar/new-b/baz/`

Answer (score 2):

Use find with `-o` (or operand) and (escaped) parentheses:

```
find $dir \( -name 'new*.java' -o -name 'new*.c' \)
```

Technically the parentheses aren't required unless you add other filters.

You can also use a regexp:

```
find . -regextype egrep -regex '.*/new-.*\.(java|c)'
```

(the regexp should match the full path, hence the `.*/` at the start.

Answer (score 0):

It's kind of ugly, but this would output each file extension you wanted in your current directory and it's sub-directories

```
find . -type f -name '*.c' && find . -type f -name '*.h' && find . -type f -name '*.java'
```

EDIT:

If you have to use ls then this might be what you are looking for:

```
ls | grep -r '*.c\|*.h\|*.java' | grep new-*
```

Comment: Thank you! But I need to use ls and the subdirectories have to start with "new-"

Comment: I updated my comment for doing it with ls, but its typically better to use find